# One function is overriding other in javascript - yii2

Tags: javascript, yii2

I'm trying to get productname,productiondate and prodqty  from production model in gridview and also the `sum(prodqty)` in a textbox when a particular product is selected. The gridview is populating fine. I can see the `sum(prodqty)` javascript alert in a flash. But it's not passing to the textbox. The error message is - `uncaught exception: unknown (can't convert to string)` Again if I comment out the code for the gridview, the sum(prodqty) is shown in the textbox but I don't get the gridview.

My Controller Actions -

```
public function actionIndex()
    {
        $catId = yii::$app->request->get('catId');
        $searchModel = new ProductionSearch();
        $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams, $catId);
        $searchModel2 = new ProductsalesSearch();
        $dataProvider2 = $searchModel2->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams, $catId);
        $model = new Productnames();
        return $this->render('index', [
            'searchModel' => $searchModel,
            'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
            'searchModel2' => $searchModel2,
            'dataProvider2' => $dataProvider2,
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }
public function actionGetForProduction($catid)
    {
        $production = Production::find()->select('sum(prodqty) as totalproduction')->where(['productname'=>$catid])->asArray()->one();
        echo Json::encode($production);
    }
```

Javascript code in index.php -

```
<?php
/* start getting the textboxes */
$script = <<< JS
$(function(){
    $('#catid').change(function(){   
        getIndexpage();
        getTotalproduction();
    });

    var catid = $(this).val();

    var getIndexpage = function(){        
        var catid = String($('#catid').val());
        window.location = 'index.php?r=productstockbook/production/index&catId='+catid;       

    } ;
    var getTotalproduction = function(){        
        var catid = String($('#catid').val());
        $.get('index.php?r=productstockbook/production/get-for-production',{ catid : catid }, function(data){
        alert(data);
        var data = $.parseJSON(data);
        $('#production').attr('value',data.totalproduction);
    });

    } ;
});


JS;
$this->registerJs($script);
/* end getting the textboxes */
?>
```

The error screenshot -
[image]

**What happens if I comment out the window.location code -** 
Code -

```
<?php
/* start getting the textboxes */
$script = <<< JS
$(function(){
    $('#catid').change(function(){   
        getIndexpage();
        getTotalproduction();
    });

    var catid = $(this).val();

    var getIndexpage = function(){        
        var catid = String($('#catid').val());
        //window.location = 'index.php?r=productstockbook/production/index&catId='+catid;       

    } ;
    var getTotalproduction = function(){        
        var catid = String($('#catid').val());
        $.get('index.php?r=productstockbook/production/get-for-production',{ catid : catid }, function(data){
        alert(data);
        var data = $.parseJSON(data);
        $('#production').attr('value',data.totalproduction);
    });

    } ;
});


JS;
$this->registerJs($script);
/* end getting the textboxes */
?>
```

Screenshot if I comment out window.location code - 
[image]

We can see that the alert is staying but the gridview is obviously not populating.

Complete Controller Code -

```
<?php

namespace frontend\modules\productstockbook\controllers;

use Yii;
use frontend\modules\productstockbook\models\Production;
use frontend\modules\productstockbook\models\ProductionSearch;
use yii\web\Controller;
use yii\web\NotFoundHttpException;
use yii\filters\VerbFilter;
use frontend\modules\productstockbook\models\ProductsalesSearch;
use yii\helpers\Html;
use frontend\modules\productstockbook\models\Productnames;
use yii\helpers\Json;

/**
 * ProductionController implements the CRUD actions for Production model.
 */
class ProductionController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function behaviors()
    {
        return [
            'verbs' => [
                'class' => VerbFilter::className(),
                'actions' => [
                    'delete' => ['POST'],
                ],
            ],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Lists all Production models.
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function actionIndex()
    {
        $catId = yii::$app->request->get('catId');
        $searchModel = new ProductionSearch();
        $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams, $catId);
        $searchModel2 = new ProductsalesSearch();
        $dataProvider2 = $searchModel2->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams, $catId);
        $model = new Productnames();
        return $this->render('index', [
            'searchModel' => $searchModel,
            'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
            'searchModel2' => $searchModel2,
            'dataProvider2' => $dataProvider2,
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Displays a single Production model.
     * @param integer $id
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function actionView($id)
    {
        return $this->render('view', [
            'model' => $this->findModel($id),
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Creates a new Production model.
     * If creation is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'view' page.
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function actionCreate()
    {
        $model = new Production();

        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
            return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->productionid]);
        } else {
            return $this->render('create', [
                'model' => $model,
            ]);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Updates an existing Production model.
     * If update is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'view' page.
     * @param integer $id
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function actionUpdate($id)
    {
        $model = $this->findModel($id);

        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
            return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->productionid]);
        } else {
            return $this->render('update', [
                'model' => $model,
            ]);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Deletes an existing Production model.
     * If deletion is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'index' page.
     * @param integer $id
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function actionDelete($id)
    {
        $this->findModel($id)->delete();

        return $this->redirect(['index']);
    }

    /**
     * Finds the Production model based on its primary key value.
     * If the model is not found, a 404 HTTP exception will be thrown.
     * @param integer $id
     * @return Production the loaded model
     * @throws NotFoundHttpException if the model cannot be found
     */
    protected function findModel($id)
    {
        if (($model = Production::findOne($id)) !== null) {
            return $model;
        } else {
            throw new NotFoundHttpException('The requested page does not exist.');
        }
    }
    public function actionGetForProduction($catid)
    {
        $production = Production::find()->select('sum(prodqty) as totalproduction')->where(['productname'=>$catid])->asArray()->one();
        echo Json::encode($production);
    }

}
```

Complete index.php code -

```
<?php

use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\grid\GridView;
use kartik\select2\Select2;
use yii\helpers\ArrayHelper;
use frontend\modules\productstockbook\models\Productnames;
use yii\helpers\Json;

/* @var $this yii\web\View */
/* @var $searchModel frontend\modules\productstockbook\models\ProductionSearch */
/* @var $dataProvider yii\data\ActiveDataProvider */

$this->title = 'Product Stock Book';
$this->params['breadcrumbs'][] = $this->title;
?>
<div class="production-index">

    <h1><?= Html::encode($this->title) ?></h1>
    <?php // echo $this->render('_search', ['model' => $searchModel]); ?>

    <?php
        echo Select2::widget([
        'model' => $model,
        'attribute' => 'productnames_productname',
        'data' => ArrayHelper::map(Productnames::find()->all(),'productnames_productname','productnames_productname'),
        'options' => ['placeholder' => 'Select Product', 'id' => 'catid'],
        'pluginOptions' => [
            'allowClear' => true
        ],
        ]);
    ?>
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-lg-4" >
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="production" readonly placeholder ="Production">                
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-lg-4" >
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="sell" readonly placeholder ="Sell">                
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-lg-4" >
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="stock" readonly placeholder ="Stock">                
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class= 'col-md-6'>
    <?= GridView::widget([
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'filterModel' => $searchModel,
        'columns' => [
            ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],

            //'productionid',
            'productiondate',
            //'itemid',
            'productname',
            //'batchno',
            'prodqty',

            //['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn'],
        ],
    ]); ?>
</div>

<div class='col-md-6'>

    <?php
        echo GridView::widget([
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider2,
        'filterModel' => $searchModel2,
        'columns' => [
            ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],

            'billdate',
            'productsales_partyname',
            'productname',
            'total',

        ], 
        ]); 
      ?>
  </div>
</div>


<?php
/* start getting the textboxes */
$script = <<< JS
$(function(){
    $('#catid').change(function(){   
        getIndexpage();
        getTotalproduction();
    });

    var catid = $(this).val();

    var getIndexpage = function(){        
        var catid = String($('#catid').val());
        //window.location = 'index.php?r=productstockbook/production/index&catId='+catid;       

    } ;
    var getTotalproduction = function(){        
        var catid = String($('#catid').val());
        $.get('index.php?r=productstockbook/production/get-for-production',{ catid : catid }, function(data){
        alert(data);
        var data = $.parseJSON(data);
        $('#production').attr('value',data.totalproduction);
    });

    } ;
});


JS;
$this->registerJs($script);
/* end getting the textboxes */
?>
```

**Update -**

I got that after `window.location` the page is redirected to a new page and all the javascript code after new page load should be written in the new page. Please let me know how to write codes in the new file. As this page is loaded dynamically I'm not so sure where to call the javascript functions.

Comment: So you get `alert(data);` value but not in textbox? I see you're doing JSON parsing but then taking specific part of variable. Maybe it doesn't exist or you don't get from parsing what you expect? What if you move your `alert(data);` one line below (below `var data = ...`)?

Comment: Same result. I get alert(data) for a blink of an eye. and then it dissapears. The error message in console remains unchanged.

Comment: What do you mean it dissapears? It should dissapear only when you click on "OK" button or the page is reloaded. The error message is of course the same because we didn't change anything in printing to console. Can you copy-paste your output from `data` (might be long, so use http://pastebin.com/ for output).

Comment: That is what I'm trying to say. Normally the alert waits until I press the OK button. But for this code. It doesn't stays there. I'm attaching a screenshot with commenting out the window.location part that is the gridview part. Then the alert stays until I click ok. I've added additional information in the question.

Comment: `Alert` won't stay since you're redirecting to specific page. I have tried nearly identical code to yours and for me it works. Then show me how your that field looks like (code).

Comment: I've added complete Controller and Complete index.php code in the question. Please let me know if anything else is needed.

Comment: I'm not capable of producing your error. It must be something very specific (to you). Write `alert(data.totalproduction);` and check what you get.

Comment: Same "uncaught exception: unknown (can't convert to string)". Do you see anything with the window.location code when you run the code. Or can I replace this anything else?

Comment: I have actually added below `$(function(){` these lines: `$(document).ready(function(e) {    getTotalproduction();    });` since I don't get the Ajax request until I edit that field.

Comment: OK. Please let me know if you find any solution. I'm really stuck here.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120953/discussion-between-edvin-tenovimas-and-tanmay).