# Filter gridview with select2 widget outside of the grid in yii2

Tags: yii2

I'm trying to filter gridviews  by select2 widget. But the select2 widget should not be within the gridview. It would be like in the screenshot - 
[image]
And when I select the select2 widget the data is filtered.
My index.php code is -

```
<?php

use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\grid\GridView;
use kartik\select2\Select2;
use yii\helpers\ArrayHelper;
use frontend\modules\productstockbook\models\Productnames;
use yii\helpers\Json;

/* @var $this yii\web\View */
/* @var $searchModel frontend\modules\productstockbook\models\ProductionSearch */
/* @var $dataProvider yii\data\ActiveDataProvider */

$this->title = 'Product Stock Book';
$this->params['breadcrumbs'][] = $this->title;
?>
<div class="production-index">

    <h1><?= Html::encode($this->title) ?></h1>
    <?php // echo $this->render('_search', ['model' => $searchModel]); ?>

    <?php
        echo Select2::widget([
        'model' => $model,
        'attribute' => 'productnames_productname',
        'data' => ArrayHelper::map(Productnames::find()->all(),'productnames_productname','productnames_productname'),
        'options' => ['placeholder' => 'Select Product', 'id' => 'catid'],
        'pluginOptions' => [
            'allowClear' => true
        ],
        ]);
    ?>
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-lg-3" >
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="production" readonly placeholder ="Production">                
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-lg-3" >
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="sell" readonly placeholder ="Sell">                
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-lg-3" >
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="stock" readonly placeholder ="Stock">                
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-lg-3" >
                    <button type="button" id="search" class="btn btn-primary"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" aria-hidden="true"></span></button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class= 'col-md-6'>
    <?= GridView::widget([
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'filterModel' => $searchModel,
        'columns' => [
            ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],

            //'productionid',
            'productiondate',
            //'itemid',
            'productname',
            //'batchno',
            'prodqty',

            //['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn'],
        ],
    ]); ?>
</div>

<div class='col-md-6'>

    <?php
        echo GridView::widget([
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider2,
        'filterModel' => $searchModel2,
        'columns' => [
            ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],

            'billdate',
            'productsales_partyname',
            'productname',
            'total',

        ], 
        ]); 
      ?>
  </div>
</div>


<?php
/* start getting the textboxes */
$script = <<< JS
$(function(){
    //$(document).ready(function(e) { getTotalproduction(); });

    $('#catid').change(function(){   
        getIndexpage();
        //getTotalproduction();
        //getTotalsell();
        //getTotalstock();
    });

    var catid = $(this).val();

    var getIndexpage = function(){        
        var catid = String($('#catid').val());
        window.onbeforeunload = function(e) {return getTotalproduction();};
        window.location.href = 'index.php?r=productstockbook/production/index&catid='+catid;       

    } ;
    var getTotalproduction = function(){        
        var catid = String($('#catid').val());
        $.get('index.php?r=productstockbook/production/get-for-production',{ catid : catid }, function(data){
        //alert(data);
        var data = $.parseJSON(data);
        $('#production').attr('value',data.totalproduction);
    }); 

    } ;
    var getTotalsell = function(){        
        var catid = String($('#catid').val());
        $.get('index.php?r=productstockbook/production/get-for-sales',{ catid : catid }, function(data){
        //alert(data);
        var data = $.parseJSON(data);
        $('#sell').attr('value',data.totalsell);
    });

    };
    var getTotalstock = function(){        

        var totalproduction = parseInt($('#production').val());
        var totalsell = parseInt($('#sell').val());
        var totalstock = Math.round(totalproduction - totalsell)

        //alert(totalstock);
        if (isNaN(totalstock) || totalstock < -10000000 || totalstock > 1000000) {
        totalstock = '';
        }
        $('#stock').val(totalstock);
    };
    // var getTotalstock = function(){        

    //     var catid = String($('#catid').val());
    //     $.get('index.php?r=productstockbook/production/get-for-stock',{ catid : catid }, function(data){
    //     alert(data);
    //     var data = $.parseJSON(data);
    //     $('#stock').attr('value',data.stock);
    // });
    // };
});


JS;
$this->registerJs($script);
/* end getting the textboxes */
?>
```

My Controller code is -

```
<?php

namespace frontend\modules\productstockbook\controllers;

use Yii;
use frontend\modules\productstockbook\models\Production;
use frontend\modules\productstockbook\models\ProductionSearch;
use yii\web\Controller;
use yii\web\NotFoundHttpException;
use yii\filters\VerbFilter;
use frontend\modules\productstockbook\models\ProductsalesSearch;
use yii\helpers\Html;
use frontend\modules\productstockbook\models\Productnames;
use frontend\modules\productstockbook\models\Productsales;
use yii\helpers\Json;
use yii\db\Query;
use yii\db\Command;

/**
 * ProductionController implements the CRUD actions for Production model.
 */
class ProductionController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function behaviors()
    {
        return [
            'verbs' => [
                'class' => VerbFilter::className(),
                'actions' => [
                    'delete' => ['POST'],
                ],
            ],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Lists all Production models.
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function actionIndex()
    {
        $catid = yii::$app->request->get('catid');
        $searchModel = new ProductionSearch();
        $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams, $catid);
        $searchModel2 = new ProductsalesSearch();
        $dataProvider2 = $searchModel2->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams, $catid);
        $model = new Productnames();
        return $this->render('index', [
            'searchModel' => $searchModel,
            'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
            'searchModel2' => $searchModel2,
            'dataProvider2' => $dataProvider2,
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Displays a single Production model.
     * @param integer $id
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function actionView($id)
    {
        return $this->render('view', [
            'model' => $this->findModel($id),
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Creates a new Production model.
     * If creation is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'view' page.
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function actionCreate()
    {
        $model = new Production();

        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
            return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->productionid]);
        } else {
            return $this->render('create', [
                'model' => $model,
            ]);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Updates an existing Production model.
     * If update is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'view' page.
     * @param integer $id
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function actionUpdate($id)
    {
        $model = $this->findModel($id);

        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
            return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->productionid]);
        } else {
            return $this->render('update', [
                'model' => $model,
            ]);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Deletes an existing Production model.
     * If deletion is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'index' page.
     * @param integer $id
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function actionDelete($id)
    {
        $this->findModel($id)->delete();

        return $this->redirect(['index']);
    }

    /**
     * Finds the Production model based on its primary key value.
     * If the model is not found, a 404 HTTP exception will be thrown.
     * @param integer $id
     * @return Production the loaded model
     * @throws NotFoundHttpException if the model cannot be found
     */
    protected function findModel($id)
    {
        if (($model = Production::findOne($id)) !== null) {
            return $model;
        } else {
            throw new NotFoundHttpException('The requested page does not exist.');
        }
    }
    public function actionGetForProduction($catid)
    {
        $production = Production::find()->select('sum(prodqty) as totalproduction')->where(['productname'=>$catid])->asArray()->one();
        echo Json::encode($production);
    }

    public function actionGetForSales($catid)
    {
        $sell = Productsales::find()->select('sum(total) as totalsell')->where(['productname'=>$catid])->asArray()->one();
        echo Json::encode($sell);
    }
    // public function actionGetForStock($catid)
    // {
    //     //$stock = Productsales::find()->joinWith('Production')->select('sum(production.prodqty) - sum(productsales.total) as stock')->where(['productname'=>$catid])->asArray()->one();
    //     //echo Json::encode($stock);
    //     //$subQuery1 = (new Query())->select(['productname,sum(prodqty) as totalproduction'])->from('production')->where(['productname'=>$catid]);
    //     $subQuery2 = (new Query())->select(['productname,sum(total) as totalsell'])->from('productsales')->where(['productname'=>$catid]);
    //     $subQuery3 = (new Query())->select(['productname,(sum(prodqty) - sell.totalsell) as totalstock'])->from('production')->leftJoin(['sell' => $subQuery2],'sell.productname = productname')->where(['productname'=>$catid]);
    //     echo Json::encode($subQuery3);
    // }

}
```

ProductionSearch Model code -

```
<?php

namespace frontend\modules\productstockbook\models;

use Yii;
use yii\base\Model;
use yii\data\ActiveDataProvider;
use frontend\modules\productstockbook\models\Production;

/**
 * ProductionSearch represents the model behind the search form about `frontend\modules\productstockbook\models\Production`.
 */
class ProductionSearch extends Production
{
    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['productionid', 'itemid', 'prodqty'], 'integer'],
            [['productiondate', 'productname', 'batchno'], 'safe'],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function scenarios()
    {
        // bypass scenarios() implementation in the parent class
        return Model::scenarios();
    }

    /**
     * Creates data provider instance with search query applied
     *
     * @param array $params
     *
     * @return ActiveDataProvider
     */
    public function search($params,$catid)
    {
        $query = Production::find()
                //->select(['productionid', 'productiondate', 'itemid', 'productname', 'batchno', 'prodqty'])
                ->orDerBy([
                        'productiondate'=>SORT_DESC,
                    ])
                ->andWhere(['productname' => $catid]);
        // add conditions that should always apply here

        $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
            'query' => $query,
        ]);

        $this->load($params);

        if (!$this->validate()) {
            // uncomment the following line if you do not want to return any records when validation fails
            // $query->where('0=1');
            return $dataProvider;
        }

        // grid filtering conditions
        $query->andFilterWhere([
            'productionid' => $this->productionid,
            'productiondate' => $this->productiondate,
            'itemid' => $this->itemid,
            'prodqty' => $this->prodqty,
        ]);

        $query->andFilterWhere(['like', 'productname', $this->productname])
            ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'batchno', $this->batchno]);

        return $dataProvider;
    }
}
```

ProductsalesSearch Model Code -

```
<?php

namespace frontend\modules\productstockbook\models;

use Yii;
use yii\base\Model;
use yii\data\ActiveDataProvider;
use frontend\modules\productstockbook\models\Productsales;

/**
 * ProductsalesSearch represents the model behind the search form about `frontend\modules\productstockbook\models\Productsales`.
 */
class ProductsalesSearch extends Productsales
{
    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['id', 'productsales_ebillid', 'discount'], 'integer'],
            [['year', 'console', 'billno', 'billdate', 'productsales_partyname', 'itemid', 'productname', 'batchno', 'expdate', 'productiondate', 'prodqty', 'qty', 'free', 'total'], 'safe'],
            [['mrp', 'rate'], 'number'],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function scenarios()
    {
        // bypass scenarios() implementation in the parent class
        return Model::scenarios();
    }

    /**
     * Creates data provider instance with search query applied
     *
     * @param array $params
     *
     * @return ActiveDataProvider
     */
    public function search($params,$catid)
    {
        $query = Productsales::find()

                ->orDerBy([
                        'billdate'=>SORT_DESC,
                    ])
                ->andWhere(['productname' => $catid]);
        // add conditions that should always apply here

        $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
            'query' => $query,
        ]);

        $this->load($params);

        if (!$this->validate()) {
            // uncomment the following line if you do not want to return any records when validation fails
            // $query->where('0=1');
            return $dataProvider;
        }

        // grid filtering conditions
        $query->andFilterWhere([
            'id' => $this->id,
            'productsales_ebillid' => $this->productsales_ebillid,
            'billdate' => $this->billdate,
            'expdate' => $this->expdate,
            'mrp' => $this->mrp,
            'rate' => $this->rate,
            'productiondate' => $this->productiondate,
            'discount' => $this->discount,
        ]);

        $query->andFilterWhere(['like', 'year', $this->year])
            ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'console', $this->console])
            ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'billno', $this->billno])
            ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'productsales_partyname', $this->productsales_partyname])
            ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'itemid', $this->itemid])
            ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'productname', $this->productname])
            ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'batchno', $this->batchno])
            ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'prodqty', $this->prodqty])
            ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'qty', $this->qty])
            ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'free', $this->free])
            ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'total', $this->total]);

        return $dataProvider;
    }
     // public function gettotalProduction()
     //    {
     //            return $this->c_name.' - '.$this->c_address.' - '.$this->c_mobileno;
     //    }
}
```

My point is that in the javascript in index.php file the following code is being used -

```
window.location.href = 'index.php?r=productstockbook/production/index&catid='+catid;
```

I don't want the page to be relocated. Because if it relocates I cannot get sum(prodqty) and sum(total) in the textboxes as you can see in the page beaceuse the page is being relocated. How can I achieve this without relocating the page? This is same question as [Filter data with kartik Select2 widget in gridview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38605035/filter-data-with-kartik-select2-widget-in-gridview/38606200#comment65308667_38606200)

**Update**
Currently after working on Edvin's solution - I'm facing the following error - 
[image]

Comment: And what do you want to do with data you are getting when selecting an option? Btw, how did you go with overriding JS function? I actually wasn't informed that you have sent a message to me.

Comment: I was trying with the data I got in the web,anyways. I want 2 things to happen when the select2 widget is being selected. 1. To Show the Production and Producsales gridview filtered with the selected value. 2. To display the sum(prodqty) in the Production Textbox, sum(productsales) in the sales textbox and the difference between these two in the stock textbox.

Comment: Well, to get filtered, you will need to reload the page. But what's the problem with getting the total value of all filtered elements? Just use JavaScript to loop through each cell and get value.

Comment: Hi Edvin, in the index.php I've written javascript code to get the sum of column. But I guess you are not askuing me to do it in the same way. I'm not so sure how to loop through each cell and get value. Please share the code with me. You already have all the details I guess.

Comment: Well, I can write a code to calculate the sum of the last column in each table and give a the difference between them. I hope it's what you wanted.

Comment: That's right. That will be very helpful. I'm also trying using http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/37012-how-to-get-values-from-gridview-to-compute-total/. But getting errors.

Comment: Hello, so was my answer solved your issue?

Comment: No Edvin. I couldn't make it.

Comment: You haven't told me that, I didn't know. Ok, you can do this. Use DEV tools and find object (table) by ID (something like `$('#w3')`). Write that ID in my JS code. And check if it works then.

Comment: @EdvinTenovimas I was bit busy in other parts. Sorry for that. I've never used DEV tool before. Can you write the full code for me? That will be helpful.

Comment: In JavaScript that pretty much the full code. The problem is that IDs can change during different sessions, that's why my code might not work. You can also print full souce with CTRL+U I believe.

Comment: My problem is exactly the same. Your code works after every page loads. Right? That means it calculates the sum of a gridview column after the page loads. So it should not be ID specific - as far I understand. Please let me know if I'm wrong and also what I need to do or anything you want from my end. I'm pretty new in in yii.

Comment: So you're saying it works on every page reload but not without reloading?

Comment: I am trying to say that I need to filter the grid with the data but not by  relocating the page. By that we'll be able to pass data from controller itself to the textbox.

Answer (score 0):

Since I see it already filters data (but with page reload), I moved to part 2 where you asked for sum of specific column.

I couldn't think of better solution at the moment but this should work for now. Note that it might be only **temporary solution** because this code is "fragile" (adding an additional column, changing tables' ID, etc.) will break this and you will forced to modify this code. Also please note it takes the sum of all printed rows (meaning only the visible (1st by default) is counted).

I have used something similar before and since IDs are somewhat static, it rarely breaks for me.

```
$(document).on('ready', function(e) {
        var row0 = $('#w0')[0]['childNodes'][2]['childNodes'][2]['children'];
        var row1 = $('#w1')[0]['childNodes'][2]['childNodes'][2]['children'];
        var total0 = 0;
        var total1 = 0;

        for (var i = 0; i < row0.length; i++) {
            total0 += parseInt(row0[i]['children'][3]['textContent'], 10);
        }

        for (var i = 0; i < row1.length; i++) {
            total1 += parseInt(row1[i]['children'][4]['textContent'], 10);
        }
                                                // ^ This number takes (n+1)th column
        console.log('First table total value: ' + total0);
        console.log('Second table total value: ' + total1);
        console.log('Difference between 1st and 2nd total values: ' + (total0 - total1));
    })
```

This will work, assuming your tables' IDs are "w0" (first table) and "w1" (second table) and there are exactly that amount of columns in your represented picture.

In case there are a lot of records, you can increase the size of how many rows to print in table by adding additional lines in Model:

```
$dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
            'query' => $query,
            'pagination' => [
                'pageSize' => 30,
            ]
        ]);
```

Comment: Got error - TypeError: $(...)[0].childNodes[2] is undefined
 
var row1 = $('#w1')[0]['childNodes'][2]['childNodes'][2]['children'];

Comment: Is the ID correct (matches in website and in code)? Hmm... Could you send me a link with your website's tables' source code?

Comment: I'm working in a local computer. I've made id of production gridview as - "prodtable" and productsales gridview as - "selltable". and changed w0 to prodtable and w1 to selltable. But still getting kind of same error - "TypeError: $(...)[0].childNodes[2].childNodes[2] is undefined
var row0 = $('#prodtable')[0]['childNodes'][2]['childNodes'][2]['children'];"  and the error arrowmark is here - "var row0 = $(". I'm adding the screenshot in the question.

Comment: @Tanmay How to solve this, I know, but hard to explain. It's a little difficult to understand how to "create" a way to cell through elements... I wonder about that arrow... Does that mean it doesn't recognize jQuery syntax or it's just a random arrow?.. What about if you remove that part and leave another one (there are two parts).

Comment: Hi Edvin, I'm stuck in this. What is childNodes and children?

Comment: @Tanmay Well, we can start from provided your rendered source code (you know, HTML content). I'll see if that's enough for me to improve my answer.

Comment: Hi Edvin, I've already given the index.php code in the question. Please let me know if you need anything from me. I guess that is all the HTML from my end.